# Как не выписывать пустые значения?

Tags: python, переменные

Всем доброго дня!
я совсем новичок в программировании
при парсинге у меня переменная иногда содержит текст, а иногда нет
я записываю в файл все что содержит переменная, но хотел бы записывать только если в переменной что то есть, а когда там пусто что бы он не записывал мне пустую строчку
записывает все самым простым способом

```
f = open("list.txt", "a")
f.write(Peremenaya + '\n')
f.close()
```

попробовал несколько способов описаных в интернете типо:

```
for i in Peremenaya:
  if str(Peremenaya) != "":
     f = open("list.txt", "a")
     f.write(Peremenaya + '\n')
     f.close()
```

таким образом пустые значения не записываются вроде как, но теперь он мне продублировал первое содержимое 77 раз и 84 раза другое значение, не понимаю по чему =)
буду признателен если кто то поможет разобраться)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно просто проверять пустая ли переменная, а не проходить по ней циклом каждый раз получая по символу.

```
if variable: # variable - нужная нам переменная 
    f = open("list.txt", "a")
    f.write(variable + '\n')
    f.close()
```

Можно не приводить переменную к str, не сравнивать ее с пустой строкой и не смотреть длину. Т.к. это все делает if по умолчанию(если переменная строка то смотрит длину а если нет то приводит к bool).

Comment: Не знал что так можно, спасибо все работает как задумано